# Run Hidden Selenium Browser

Tags: python, selenium

I use selenium library and when it run a browser open

and show all link to want go . i want when a selenium

driver run , it run in a hidden browser and User can't

know we use a selenium browser for this work . tnx

( 'Lang::Python' )

>

Comment: http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/headless-browser-testing-selenium-webdriver/

Comment: Tnx , It's work very nice

Answer (score 0):

Try the headless Chrome mode. You can find example of chromedriver initialization with the code snippets for python in this [post](https://medium.com/@pyzzled/running-headless-chrome-with-selenium-in-python-3f42d1f5ff1d)